# Ajax Validation in Struts 2

Tags: ajax, struts2

It is a Struts 2 MVC Project.I added jar file struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.2

```
 Error :
 HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 22
```

exception

```
19: <s:textfield name="name" label="UserName"></s:textfield>
20: <s:textfield name="email" label="Emai ID"></s:textfield>
21: <s:password name="password" label="Password">  </s:password>
22: <d:submit validate="true" type="image" src="register-now.jpg">  </d:submit>
23: </s:form>
24: </body>
25: </html>
```

I cannot ditect the problem. Please help me or any idea?

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:426)
root cause

Comment: Neither can we, because you didn't post the stack trace.

Comment: Mr. Dave Newton , I added the stack trace on my question

Comment: Not the whole thing, apparently. Did you declare the taglib in the JSP?